# when applying a color in the display equation, above and below display space varying

Tags: macros, equations, color, amsmath

Trying to apply a color in the display equation, I just modified the environment from `amsmath.sty`. The above and below space is modified (increased space) when applying color, see the below image, in the first equation the below space is more, and the second equation above space is more.

How to fix the default space mentioned in the `\abovedisplayskip \belowdisplayskip`?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjkq8.png]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,color}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{equation}{\color{red}%
  \incr@eqnum
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredfalse \global\@eqnswtrue
  \mathdisplay{equation}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\def\start@align#1#2#3{\color{red}%
    \let\xatlevel@#1% always \z@, \@ne, or \tw@
    \maxfields@#3\relax
    \ifnum\maxfields@>\m@ne
        \checkat@true
        \ifnum\xatlevel@=\tw@
            \xxat@true
        \fi
        \multiply\maxfields@\tw@
    \else
        \checkat@false
    \fi
    \ifingather@
        \iffalse{\fi\ifnum0=`}\fi
        \DN@{\vcenter\bgroup\savealignstate@\align@#2}%
    \else
        \ifmmode
          \if@display
             \DN@{\align@recover}%
          \else
            \nomath@env
            \DN@{\@namedef{end\@currenvir}{}\@gobble}%
          \fi
        \else
            $$%
            \let\split\insplit@
            \DN@{\align@#2}%
        \fi
    \fi
    \collect@body\next@
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

text $inline equation a+b$
\[
a = b, \text{\qquad by assumption}
\]
Note the spacing command \qquad in the argument of \text. You could also
type
\[
a = b, \qquad \text{by assumption}
\]
because \qquad works in math as well as in text (see Sections 8.1 and B.9).
\begin{equation}\label{E:firstInt}
aa+bb \sin x \, dx = 2
\end{equation}
because \qquad works in math as well as in text (see Sections 8.1 and B.9).
\begin{equation}\label{E:firstInt}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin x \, dx = 2
\end{equation}

type the following, using as the line separator and \& as the alignment point:
\begin{align}
r^{2} &= s^{2} + t^{2}, \label{E:Pyth}\\
2u + 1 &= v + w^{\alpha}, \label{E:alpha}\\
x &= \frac{y + z}{\sqrt{s + 2u}};\label{E:frac}
\end{align}
is typed as follows:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
-x^{2}, &\text{if $x < 0$;}\\
\alpha + x, &\text{if $0 \leq x \leq 1$;}\\
x^{2}, &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
which is typed as
\begin{gather*}
\overleftarrow{a} \quad \overrightarrow{aa}\\
\overleftrightarrow{aaa} \quad \underleftarrow{aaaa}\quad
\underrightarrow{aaaaa} \quad \underleftrightarrow{aaaaaa}
\end{gather*}

This formula is typed as
\begin{multline}\label{E:mm2}
(x_{1} x_{2} x_{3} x_{4} x_{5} x_{6})^{2}\\
+ (y_{1} y_{2} y_{3} y_{4} y_{5}
+ y_{1} y_{3} y_{4} y_{5} y_{6}
+ y_{1} y_{2} y_{4} y_{5} y_{6}
+ y_{1} y_{2} y_{3} y_{5} y_{6})^{2}\\
+ (z_{1} z_{2} z_{3} z_{4} z_{5}
+ z_{1} z_{3} z_{4} z_{5} z_{6}
+ z_{1} z_{2} z_{4} z_{5} z_{6}
+ z_{1} z_{2} z_{3} z_{5} z_{6})^{2}\\
+ (u_{1} u_{2} u_{3} u_{4} + u_{1} u_{2} u_{3} u_{5}
+ u_{1} u_{2} u_{4} u_{5} + u_{1} u_{3} u_{4} u_{5})^{2}
\end{multline}


\end{document}
```

Comment: use `$$\begingroup\color{red}` here and `\endgroup $$`  where you close it, to keep the color in the math

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the above solution not working for align environment

Comment: Does `\let\oldequation\equation
\let\oldendequation\endequation
\renewenvironment{equation}{
    \oldequation
    \bgroup
    \color{red}
}{
    \egroup
    \oldendequation
}` instead of your redefinition do the job?